# How can I make the C++ compiler support template for STL?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, boost, spack

I am trying to install `hpctoolkit` using `Spack`. In order to do that, I executed :

```
git clone https://github.com/spack/spack.git
cd spack/share/spack
source setup-env.sh 
spack fetch -D hpctoolkit
spack install hpctoolkit
```

I can't execute the last command because I get the following error:

```
Error: ProcessError: Command exited with status 1:
    './bootstrap.sh' '--prefix=/home/hakim/spack/opt/spack/linux-ubuntu20.04-haswell/gcc-10.2.0/boost-1.76.0-oc2u6jxritfsbci4xkhr5lov3i4o4riq' '--with-toolset=gcc' '--with-libraries=serialization,atomic,log,exception,regex,math,random,program_options,wave,iostreams,chrono,system,test,graph,locale,timer,filesystem,date_time,thread' '--without-icu'
```

It recommended me to take a look at build log by displaying the following message:

```
See build log for details:
  /tmp/hakim/spack-stage/spack-stage-boost-1.76.0-oc2u6jxritfsbci4xkhr5lov3i4o4riq/spack-build-out.txt
```

and the previous file contains:

```
A C++11 capable compiler is required for building the B2 engine.
Toolset 'gcc' does not appear to support C++11.

> g++ -x c++ -std=c++11  check_cxx11.cpp
ERROR: Compiler 'gcc@9.3.0' does not support compiling C++ programs.
```

In order to display the compilers, I used the command:

```
spack compiler list
```

and the result is:

```
==> Available compilers
-- clang ubuntu20.04-x86_64 -------------------------------------
clang@10.0.0  clang@7.0.1

-- gcc ubuntu20.04-x86_64 ---------------------------------------
gcc@9.3.0  gcc@7.5.0
```

In order to get rid of the version 'gcc@9.3.0', I modified compilers.yaml which is a separate file to store information about available compilers.

In my case, I did:

```
cd ~/.spack/linux
emacs compilers.yaml &
```

and found (I'm displaying only the part related to the gcc compiler):

```
compilers:
- compiler:
        spec: gcc@7.5.0
        paths:
          cc: /usr/bin/gcc-7
          cxx: null
          f77: /usr/bin/gfortran-7
          fc: /usr/bin/gfortran-7
        flags: {}
        operating_system: ubuntu20.04
        target: x86_64
        modules: []
        environment: {}
        extra_rpaths: []

- compiler:
    spec: gcc@9.3.0
    paths:
      cc: /usr/bin/gcc-9
      cxx: null
      f77: /usr/bin/gfortran-9
      fc: /usr/bin/gfortran-9
    flags: {}
    operating_system: ubuntu20.04
    target: x86_64
    modules: []
    environment: {}
    extra_rpaths: []
```

In order to get rid of gcc@9.3.0, I just deleted its part. I verify now the list of compilers and I should find:

```
-- clang ubuntu20.04-x86_64 -------------------------------------
clang@10.0.0  clang@7.0.1

-- gcc ubuntu20.04-x86_64 ---------------------------------------
gcc@7.5.0
```

And now, when I execute the command:

```
spack install hpctoolkit
```

the error is different. I get :

```
=> Error: CompilerAccessError: Compiler 'gcc@7.5.0' has executables that are missing or are not executable: ['/usr/bin/gfortran-7', '/usr/bin/gfortran-7']

/home/hakim/spack/lib/spack/spack/build_environment.py:937, in _setup_pkg_and_run:
        934        tb_string = traceback.format_exc()
        935
        936        # build up some context from the offending package so we can
  >>    937        # show that, too.
        938        package_context = get_package_context(tb)
        939
        940        logfile = None


==> Error: hpctoolkit-2021.05.15-jkofhcw73pap6ciacwcv2mtcv6uf3n2e: Package was not installed
==> Error: Installation request failed.  Refer to reported errors for failing package(s).
```

I think the gcc@7.5.0 compiler has been wrongly installed since he tells me that it has executables that are missing or are not executable.

I tried with gcc@7.5.0, gcc@9.3.0 and gcc@10.2.0 but in vain .. (I want to mention that all the compilers are installed in `/usr/bin`)

Any help, please ?

Comment: What does the body of the question have to do with "How can I make the C++ compiler support template for STL?"?

Comment: @eerorika when I execute the command `spack solve zlib`, I get : `checking whether the C++ compiler supports templates for STL... configure: error: no`. That's why !

Comment: C++ support for gcc is in a separate package `g++`, do you have that installed? It also needs gfortran (same version as gcc).

Comment: `cxx: null` in the config probably should be path to g++ (i don't really know what these configs are)

Comment: @dewaffled  Thanks a lot ! I forgot to precise `cxx:/usr/bin/g++-9` for gcc@9.3.0. It works now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to fix this error, you should precise the path to g++.
In my case, here is the updated content of my compilers.yaml file:

```
compilers:
- compiler:
        spec: gcc@7.5.0
        paths:
          cc: /usr/bin/gcc-7
          cxx: null
          f77: /usr/bin/gfortran-7
          fc: /usr/bin/gfortran-7
        flags: {}
        operating_system: ubuntu20.04
        target: x86_64
        modules: []
        environment: {}
        extra_rpaths: []

- compiler:
    spec: gcc@9.3.0
    paths:
      cc: /usr/bin/gcc-9
      cxx: /usr/bin/g++-9
      f77: /usr/bin/gfortran-9
      fc: /usr/bin/gfortran-9
    flags: {}
    operating_system: ubuntu20.04
    target: x86_64
    modules: []
    environment: {}
    extra_rpaths: []
```

Now, it should work perfectly.

Comment: Where would I put a compilers.yaml file? I can't find anything meaningful in the docs on this?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue after running Spack and having it fail because I was missing gcc-c++. I installed gcc-c++ with yum, removed the previous gcc entry from ~/.compilers.yaml and then reran

`spack compiler find`

which properly add the new gxx path.

Comment: Don't edit my answer into a question, thank you.